# How to configure allegro in wxdevc++

Tags: dev-c++, allegro

I have searched a lot on the web regarding how to setup allegro on wxdevc++(an extension of the old devc++)

I planned to switch to wxdevcpp from old devcpp, I downloaded and installed allegro 4.2.1 and also added the parameters and directories in the project options but it gives the error

```
    allegro.h: no such file or directory.
```

Please help out , the whole night has passed searching about it.
For additional information i am here.

I am using windows8 32 bit.

Comment: Download Microsoft Visual C++ Express. (Or any other compiler except Dev C++ and its bastard children)

Comment: yeah I had switched to Microsoft Visual C++ Express last night, but for knowledge , what is the problem with wxdevcpp? Why isn't it compiling allegro?  or is this any issue due to windows8?

Comment: It's an issue with Dev C++, it is practically no longer actively being developed.